# Using ArrayList to do changes to my array and then converting it back to array, array is not changed

Tags: java, arrays, list, java-8, java-stream

I have an int[] array, so I am converting it to an ArrayList, adding some elements to it and then converting it back to an array, however the final array after calling my method is unchanged for some reason.

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5}


public static int[] method(int[] arr){
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        list.add(arr[i]);
    }
    list.add(6);        
    arr = list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
    return arr;
}
```

What is happening is that my method is returning {1,2,3,4,5}. However, if I call sysout Arrays.toString(arr) inside my method, the output is {1,2,3,4,5,6}. Can some explain what is happening? Thanks

Comment: Did you use `arr = method(arr);`?

Comment: Oh, you lost your account credentials again?

Comment: @Tom excuse me?

Comment: You don't show how you call the method... and that is where the problem is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this Code, It works for me:-

```
static int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
public static int[] method(int[] arr){
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        list.add(arr[i]);
    }
    list.add(6);                
    int[] ret = new int[list.size()];
    for (int i=0; i <ret.length; i++)                   
        ret[i] = list.get(i).intValue();        
    return ret;
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    arr = method(arr);      
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Hope will Help you!!!

Comment: ` list.get(i).intValue();` sehr ineffizient! Besser: https://pastebin.com/0NtPf8kn

Answer (score 1):

Right now your method is not returning anything, as there is no `return` statement. Use this:

```
public static int[] method(int[] arr){
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        list.add(arr[i]);
    }
    list.add(6);        
    return list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it was just my example code. However, the problem is still present.

Comment: @J.Doe then show exactly how to you get `{1,2,3,4,5}`

Comment: Then no, 6 is also in the array

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class Test{
    public static void methodA(int[] arr){
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            list.add(arr[i]);
        }
        list.add(6);        
        arr = list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
        methodA(arr);
    }
}
```

First, it added the Array elements to the ArrayList and before converting it to Array again it added 6 to ArrayList. So Now the Array arr is {1,2,3,4,5,6}.

Answer (score 0):

Result is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Stackoverflow1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};

        //arr = method(arr);
        arr = method2(arr);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

    public static int[] method(int[] arr){
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            list.add(arr[i]);
        }
        list.add(6);
        arr = list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
        return arr;
    }



    public static int[] method2(int[] arr){
        List<Integer> list =  Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        list.add(6);
        return list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
    }
}
```